# Window scrolling jQuery animation isn’t working perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my code. I am not sure where is wrong.

**JavaScript:**

```
(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop=Math.round($('.nav').offset().top);
    if (scrollTop > 1000 ) {
      $('.nav').animate({top:0});
    }
    if (scrollTop < 1000) {
      $('.nav').animate({top:90});
    }
  });
}());
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav"></div>
<div style="display:block; height:16000px; border:1px solid #000;" id="wrp"></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/py2JL/)

Comment: Can you define not working perfectly ?

Comment: @ViewsBd put it in a fiddle and post it bro

Comment: Have you jQuery loaded first before this script?

Comment: Why should it work at all? Or what should it do? Your `scrollTop` will not change on scroll, since it equals `.nav` position relatively to window and it will not change while you're scrolling.

Comment: Btw, didn't you forget add some positioning to `.nav`? E.g. `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this demo in jsfiddle.net/sjnilan/JLduB

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop=Math.round($('.nav').offset().top);

    if (scrollTop > 100 ) {
        $('.nav').stop().animate({top:0});

    }
    if (scrollTop < 100) {
        $('.nav').stop().animate({top:90});
    }
 });
```

Comment: If this is helpful Vote it plz

Answer (score 1):

To use `top` you must set `position:relative/absolute/fixed` to the element `.nav`, depending on what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1)

```
 var scrollTop=Math.round($(document).scrollTop());
```

2)

```
 .nav{
     position:fixed;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/py2JL/1/